# Python Script to query from DynamoDb not giving all items

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have written following python code to fetch data from a table but its not fetching all the items as I want. When I check on AWS console page of DynamoDb, I can see much more entries as compared to what I get from script.

```
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import boto3
import json
import decimal
from datetime import datetime
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
import sys

# Helper class to convert a DynamoDB item to JSON.
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            if o % 1 > 0:
                return float(o)
            else:
                return int(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', aws_access_key_id = '',
        aws_secret_access_key = '',
        region_name='eu-west-1', endpoint_url="http://dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com")

mplaceId = int(sys.argv[1])
table = dynamodb.Table('XYZ')

response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('mplaceId').eq(mplaceId)
)

print('Number of entries found ', len(response['Items']))
```

I did the same thing from aws console also. Query by mplaceId.

Any reason why its happening?

Comment: DynamoDB API returns 1 MB data only. If there is more data, DDB paginates it. If LastEvaluatedKey is present in the response, you will need to paginate the result set. Documentation can be found here: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.query

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`dynamodb.Table.query()` returns at max 1MB of data. From the [`boto3` documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.query):

> A single `Query` operation will read up to the maximum number of items set (if using the `Limit` parameter) or a maximum of 1 MB of data and then apply any filtering to the results using `FilterExpression`. If `LastEvaluatedKey` is present in the response, you will need to paginate the result set. For more information, see [Paginating the Results](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Pagination) in the Amazon DynamoDB Developer Guide .

That's actually no `boto3`-limitation, but a limitation of the underlying `query`-API.

Instead of implementing pagination yourself, you can use `boto3`'s [built-in pagination](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/paginators.html) . Here is an example showing the use of the [paginator for querying DynamoDB tables](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Paginator.Query) provided by `boto3`:

```py
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

dynamodb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
paginator = dynamodb_client.get_paginator('query')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    TableName='XYZ',
    KeyConditionExpression='mplaceId = :mplaceId',
    ExpressionAttributeValues={':mplaceId': {'S' : mplaceid}}
)

for page in page_iterator:
    print(page['Items'])
```

Comment: The 1MB size limit also applies to table Scans.  This was a valid question since the common behavior for a datastore is to set a return limit to the number or records, ESPECIALLY when the limit number is stated explicitly.  See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46617575/python-dynamodb-scan-operation-not-return-all-records

Comment: The thing is this has KeyConditionExpress, doesn't return all results, searching for a way to return all results without condition or regardless of condition @Dunedan

Comment: As far as I can tell the `paginate` method does not support using the Key or Attr expression objects, meaning it's not a drop-in replacement, which forces you have to build a string query manually. Also, your example doesn't include the `TableName` parameter.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack: Thanks for your comment. I edited my answer to fix the mentioned issues.